# babel-plugin-react-css-modules aren't outputting styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I'm using babel-plugin-react-css-modules and it seems to be creating the className/styleName, but for some reason it isn't outputting the CSS so that it can be read by the module.

Here's my application: [launchpad](https://github.com/yazdog8/launchpad)

I'm using webpack 4.2.0/React 16 and use a babel configuration in the webpack.config imported from a separate config file as you can't set context in .babelrc.

here's the babel config:

```
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
       options: {
        'plugins': [
           'react-hot-loader/babel',
           'transform-runtime',
           'transform-object-rest-spread',
           'transform-class-properties',
           ['react-css-modules',
            {
              context: paths.javascript,
              'generateScopedName': '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              'filetypes': {
                '.scss': {
                  'syntax': 'postcss-scss',
                  'plugins': ['postcss-nested']
                }
               },
              'exclude': 'node_modules',
              'webpackHotModuleReloading': true
            }
          ]
        ],
        'presets': [
          'env',
          'react',
          'flow'
        ],
        'env': {
          'production': {
            'presets': ['react-optimize']
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And here is my webpack:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

const paths = require('./webpack/config').paths
const outputFiles = require('./webpack/config').outputFiles
const rules = require('./webpack/config').rules
const plugins = require('./webpack/config').plugins
const resolve = require('./webpack/config').resolve
const IS_PRODUCTION = require('./webpack/config').IS_PRODUCTION
const IS_DEVELOPMENT = require('./webpack/config').IS_DEVELOPMENT

const devServer = require('./webpack/dev-server').devServer

const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

// Default client app entry file
const entry = [
  'bootstrap-loader/extractStyles',
  path.join(paths.javascript, 'index.js')
]

plugins.push(
  // Creates vendor chunk from modules coming from node_modules folder
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    filename: outputFiles.vendor,
    minChunks (module) {
      const context = module.context
      return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0
    }
  }),
  // Builds index.html from template
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(paths.source, 'index.html'),
    path: paths.build,
    filename: 'index.html',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyJS: true,
      removeComments: true,
      useShortDoctype: true
    }
  })
)

if (IS_DEVELOPMENT) {
  // Development plugins
  plugins.push(
    // Enables HMR
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Don't emmit build when there was an error while compiling
    // No assets are emitted that include errors
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // Webpack dashboard plugin
    new DashboardPlugin()
  )

  // In development we add 'react-hot-loader' for .js/.jsx files
  // Check rules in config.js
  rules[0].use.unshift('react-hot-loader/webpack')
  entry.unshift('react-hot-loader/patch')
}

// Webpack config
module.exports = {
  devtool: IS_PRODUCTION ? false : 'eval-source-map',
  context: paths.javascript,
  watch: IS_DEVELOPMENT,
  entry,
  output: {
    path: paths.build,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: outputFiles.client
  },
  module: {
    rules
  },
  resolve,
  plugins,
  devServer
}
```

If you run `npm start` or `yarn start` the code will compile and run, and you can see a basic application layout. If you inspect the react code you will see that the style name is reflected in the component. What doesn't happen is that the style isn't being output. I can't seem to figure out why.

Any help is appreciated.